Why do I get Debug error! abort() has been called?
I am in the early stages of a project for my programming class (C++). My goal is to create a console application that will read two sets form two separate files and then write their intersection into a third file. I also need to sort the input because the sets are unordered. So far my code has worked on small sets. However I need it to process very large sets as well and that seems to cause problems.
Here is my code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void swap(int& a, int& b);
int partition(vector<int>& set, int first, int last);
void quickSort(vector<int>& set, int first, int last);


int main()
{
vector<int> v1;
vector<int> v2;

ifstream file1("SourceSeqA.txt");
if(!file1.is_open()) {
    cout << "Soubor se nepodarilo otevrit!" << endl;
}


ifstream file2("SourceSeqB.txt");
if (!file2.is_open()) {
    cout << "Soubor se nepodarilo otevrit!" << endl;
}


string line1 = "Nic";
string line2 = "Nic";

int a = 0;

while(!file1.eof()){
    getline(file1, line1);
    a = stoi(line1);
    v1.push_back(a);
}
file1.close();  


while (!file2.eof()) {
    getline(file2, line2);
    a = stoi(line2);
    v2.push_back(a);
}

file2.close();



//quickSort test

int v1Size = v1.size();
int v2Size = v2.size();

quickSort(v1, 0, v1Size - 1);
quickSort(v2, 0, v2Size - 1);


return 0;
}

void swap(int& a, int& b) {
int temp;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
}

int partition(vector<int>& set, int first, int last) {
int pivot, i;

pivot = set[last];

i = first - 1;

for (int x = first; x <= last - 1; x++) {
    if (set[x] < pivot) {
        i++;
        swap(set[i], set[x]);
    }
}

swap(set[i + 1], set[last]);
return (i + 1);
}

void quickSort(vector<int>& set, int first, int last) {

if (first < last) {
    int pivotIndex;

    pivotIndex = partition(set, first, last);

    quickSort(set, first, pivotIndex - 1);
    quickSort(set, pivotIndex + 1, last);
}
}

I've tried to test small parts of the code in order to locate the problem and it seems to be the line where I call the function stoi(). Is this function inappropriate to use for large datasets?

Please format your code consistently, it aids readability a lot. That said, you found some possible call, what are the parameters in that call when it fails? Please also read [mcve], in particular it would help if you hard-coded any input in your program, unless that input itself is the problem.

Appears to be at line ... isn't something you should ever have to say since a debugger will tell you with almost 100% certainty where the program crashes. And it will give you a stack trace so you can see how the program met such a dire end. Very handy tool, a debugger.

How large is "very large"?  Is it possible that your program runs out of memory, or that the number of data elements overflows int?  (Generally size_t should be used instead of int for anything that's a size or count of objects in memory.)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's How to debug small programs.

"it seems to be the line where I call the function stoi()" This likely means that somewhere in your very large dataset there's a line of text that cannot be parsed as an integer. Like a stray character or something.

If you have a debugger like the one in Visual Studio you can get it to stop on the exact line where it crashed. Then use the "Stack Frame" combo box on the debug toolbar to switch to your code and look at  the values of variables on that line to attempt to understand the problem. In a case like this there should be no guessing at all what the problem is.

while(!file1.eof()){ getline(file1, line1); This is wrong for reasons described here

@IgorTandetnik: Good point.  stoi throws if the string can't be converted, which since it's uncaught would typically result in an abort().  So you could track it down by catching the exception and reporting the string and the line number.

https://godbolt.org/z/jbaezrcT5 shows the program failing at the stoi on line 37 for exactly the reason Igor Tandetnik links two comments above.

The test run from @user4581301 also shows why it's important to actually handle the error instead of just printing a message that the file could not be opened. In this case you probably wanted to return from main to exit the program instead of attempting to continue without the file.

C++17 has most of what you've programmed available as part of the language itself. It'd greatly simplify the code to leverage those standard C++ facilities. q.v. https://godbolt.org/z/MbG5cMh87

Consider using C.A.R Hoare’s algorithm over Lomuto’s.
